# HIGHCHARTS - How to format yAxis.stackLabel like ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']

Tags: highcharts

How can I format yAxis.stackLabel to cut huge numbers to ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']. I found how to do it on tooltip but it doesn't work on stackLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack label on the yAxis you can change using [formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter), you need to calculate the value and return format.

```
yAxis: {
    stackLabels: {
      style: {
        color: 'black'
      },
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        let value = this.total;

        if (value > 1000) {
          return Math.floor(value / 1000) + ' k'
        } else {
          return value
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4Ln0291/1/

Comment: Thanks for an answer. That work's fine. But the point of question was how to apply yAxis labels format to stackLabel. I want to values be equals

Comment: Could you explain in more details?

Comment: @Egor let's check [lang.numericSymbols](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.numericSymbols) I suppose it's what you looking for.